# Sorry: We were unable to locate information relating to your account. having trouble with iAd Workbench

Tags: ios, xcode

I have this error when I go to my iAd workbench on iTunes Connect. I don't know, when can I see information there?

I have just written my first app with iAds, I signed and accepted the Contract and submitted my App to Apple, its in the status "Waiting for Review".

In my App, I just have one Banner that displays "You're connected to iAd".

Should I already see data there or will it appear when apple checked my app and approved it hopefully?

Thanks for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, the banner should change once you app is approved!**

You also need to download the official Appstore version of your application for the banner to be visible since you are using a special developer iAD banner for testing and building purposes.

Check here for more info:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Cheers

Comment: so it means, when my app is approved i will download it in the app store and the information will be given in the iAd Workbench about how much money I earned with it?

Comment: How much money you make depends on the duration a iAD is visible  (impressions) and if you tap on it (actions). I don't know the right stats about the revenue, but surely you can find them on the web. At this point I would also like to mention that it is against Apples guidelines to manipulate the iAD by using it as the publisher of the app.

Comment: i don't want to manipulate anything. I just want to see my earnings in my account..

Comment: Yeah, who doesn't. :) I just wanted to mention that. Not that I have tried ^^

Comment: I added my error as a picture to my thread. So this will go away as soon as my app got approved?

Comment: You just need a couple of users who are using your app once in a while. If you want to expand you revenue in advertisement try other ad providers, such as Flurry and many more!

Comment: Well I assume that they are doing some maintance work for their servers. Just check tomorrow again for changes to appear.

Comment: yeah well I have this  error since a week or something like that. I will contact the apple support tho, thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. I had a couple of problems too when I uploaded my first app. My app was in "review" for two weeks straight. A call to Apple Dev support fixed my issue.